# Wrong predictions from MNSIT keras model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to neural networks so I tried my first neural network which is pretty close to one at keras learn page,given below:

https://github.com/aakarsh1011/Neural-Network/blob/master/MNSIT%20classification.ipynb

Kindlly look at the ending where I red a random image and tried to predict it which comes out as a bag, and when trained at `epocs=5` it predicted it as a sandal.
Is something wrong with my code or labeling.

**UPDATE** - Being new to the field I didn't know the importance of epochs so I asked this question, I was afraid that I don't over-fit the model or train train too much. But there is no definite way to do this, it's all try and error. GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, as far as I can see, your code is correct. Your model predicting the wrong item can be caused by the model not being trained for long enough. I would highly recommend you to set `epochs=100` and you will be able to see the model's accuracy rise. You should generally always try to give your model as many `epochs` as possible for training. It will simply take some time. Try out some different numbers of `epochs` to find the one not taking too long, but still giving an acceptable result.